# Naive aspect implementation in ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, aop

I am trying to make a simplistic implementation of AOP in ruby. I was able to implement before and after advices, I got stuck with around advice.

This is the target class that is going to be advised:

```
class MyClass
  def method
    puts "running method"
  end
end
```

This is the Aspect class to instantiate objects capable of making advices:

```
class Aspect
  def advise(class_name, method, type, &block)
    class_name.send(:alias_method, :proceed, :method)
    class_name.send(:define_method, :method) do
      case type
      when :before
        yield
        proceed
      when :after
        proceed
        yield
      when :around
        yield(proceed) # * proceed is the old version of the method
      end
    end
  end
end
```

(*) Yield should execute the block around MyClass#proceed on the current object when method is invoked.

Creating the target and the aspect:

```
mc = MyClass.new
a = Aspect.new()
```

Invoking the method without advising it:

```
puts mc.method
```

Advising MyClass#method with around:

```
a.advise(MyClass, :method, :around) do |proceed|
  puts "First"
  proceed # this is not working *
  puts "Last"
end

puts mc.method
```

(*) I am not being able to pass something to identify the call of proceed, that is the invocation of the old method without the advice.

The output should be:

```
First
running method
Last
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, a method call looks like this:

```
receiver.method(arguments)
```

Or, you can leave off the receiver if the receiver is `self`.

So, to call a method named `proceed` on some receiver, you would write

```
receiver.proceed
```

However, in your implementation, you don't keep track of what the receiver should be, so since you don't know the receiver, you simply cannot call the method.

Note that there are lots of other problems with your approach as well. For example, if you advise multiple methods, you will alias them all to the same method, overwriting each other.

Comment: Yes, I knew about the name of the alias, but I think it could be uniquely named to avoid this problem. This is not intended to be a real application, it is just an experiment. Anyway, your answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two things going wrong here.

1. This section of code

   ```
   when :around
     yield(proceed) # * proceed is the old version of the method
   end
   ```

Calls the block given to advise providing the output of the proceed method as an argument. 
So your output probably looks something like:

```
running method
First
Last
```

2. This block

   ```
   a.advise(MyClass, :method, :around) do |proceed|
     puts "First"
     proceed # this is not working *
     puts "Last"
   end
   ```

Just evaluates the argument given as proceed. If a method is given it does not call it. So taking problem 1 into consideration in your case the original definition of method (aliased to proceed) returns nil (output of return) which will be passed as the value to the proceed argument in the block when yielded. the block ends up evaluating to something like

```
      puts "First"
      nil
      puts "Last"
```

mc.method is called.

To address the second part, you may want to consider using send. Because the inner workings of your aspect may not be known to your code that calls it. It may change over time, so what ever calls Aspect.advise shouldn't make assumptions that the original method will still be accessible. Instead, it should take an argument (the new method name) and send it to the object. Making the block passed to advise:

```
a.advise(MyClass, :method, :around) do |aliased_method_name|
  puts "First"
  send(aliased_method_name)
  puts "Last"
end
```

And adjusting the around item added to your class when advise is called to the following:

```
when :around
  yield(:proceed) # * proceed is the old version of the method
end
```

If you do both of these things, your around section will calls the provided block, using the symbol for the new alias for the overridden method.

N.B.: This approach won't work for methods that require any arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. In the definition of Aspect#advise now I use a Proc, like this:

```
when :around
    yield Proc.new { proceed }
end
```

And when calling the method to advise MyClass#method with :around parameter I use this:

```
a.advise(MyClass, :method, :around) do |original|
  puts "First"
  original.call
  puts "Last"
end
```

I got:

```
First
running method
Last
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fixed version that will work for arguments, and avoid clobbering.

```
class Aspect
  @@count = 0

  def self.advise(class_name, method, type=nil, &block)
    old_method = :"__aspect_#{method}_#{@@count += 1}"
    class_name.send(:alias_method, old_method, method)
    class_name.send(:define_method, method) do |*args, &callblock|
      case type
      when :before
        yield
        send(old_method, *args, &callblock)
      when :after
        send(old_method, *args, &callblock)
        yield
      when :around, nil
        yield lambda {
          send(old_method, *args, &callblock)
        }
      end
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  def foo(what)
    puts "Hello, #{what}!"
  end
end

Aspect.advise(Foo, :foo) do |y|
  puts "before around"
  y.yield
  puts "after around"
end
Aspect.advise(Foo, :foo, :before) do
  puts "before"
end
Aspect.advise(Foo, :foo, :after) do
  puts "after"
end

Foo.new.foo("world")
# before
# before around
# Hello, world!
# after around
# after
```